# Verilog delayed signal not toggling

Tags: verilog, delay, system-verilog, clock, assign

I have the following [Code](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ru_L):

```
`timescale 1ps / 1ps 

module tb;
localparam  t_CLOCK_PERIOD          = 1000;
bit         clk;    
bit         clk_del;

always #(t_CLOCK_PERIOD/2)      clk         = ~clk;
assign #490                     clk_del     = clk;// clk_del toggling normally
//assign #510                   clk_del     = clk;// clk_del not toggling

initial begin
    clk =1'b1;
    $display("waiting for Clock delayed");
    @(posedge clk_del);
    $display("Clock delayed");
    $finish;
end
endmodule
```

I am trying to delay a clock signal, but when I do that by more of half a period, the signal stays unassigned (it does not toggle).

What am I doing wrong? How can I delay this signal more that the half period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `clk_del` assign statement does not work with the 510 delay because the   RHS (clk) changes more quickly than the delay.  It is like you are always sampling clk when it is 0.  The assign statement is confusing, and it is not the proper way to generate two related clock signals.

You can control the phase relationship between the 2 clocks by using an initial delay for the delayed clock.  This approach is more conventional and is easier to understand:

```
always #(t_CLOCK_PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    clk_del = 1;
    #10;
    forever #(t_CLOCK_PERIOD/2) clk_del = ~clk_del;
end
```

By varying the initial value of `clk_del` and the initial delay value, you can achieve any phase relationship you want.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `clk` changing before the assignment delay as toolic points out.

This problem is independent of clock signal and can be faced on data signals too. A detailed explanation of the delays usage in verilog can be found [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf).

The proper solution to my problem was to change

`assign #510  clk_del     = clk;`

to

`always @(clk) clk_del  <= #510 clk;`